# Global Keyboard Hotkey in a Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I see there is now a chrome.commands API for keyboard shortcuts for a chrome app. Does anyone know if this API does global hotkeys? By global I mean hotkeys that trigger even if chrome does not have focus.

Comment: Try it. I guess that the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Rob W's comment will lead you to the correct answer as of today. Note, however, that a Google Summer of Code participant is working on exactly this feature. Subscribe to apps-dev@chromium.org to learn more about project progress.